# c++ using constructor as member function (for serialization)

Tags: c++, serialization, constructor

My goal is to make class Particle serializable, the question is:

when reading from istream in the derived class, can I use the Particle base class' constructor as member funtion for "initialization"?

//possible reasons of misunderstanding:
I know I could write setters, but I stumbled upon this option/idea when codeblocks showed the constructor as available member function when applying access operator on an instance of Particle. I never heared of this way of "late" initialization, but I'd like it more than writing tons of setters...

So basically, is this code correct?

```
using namespace std;

struct Serializable {
    virtual void write(ostream&) const = 0;
    virtual void read(istream&) = 0;
    virtual ~Serializable() {}
};

class Particle {
    double X, Y;
public:
    Particle(double x=0, double y=0) :X(x), Y(y) {}
    //...
};

class PParticle: Particle, Serializable {
    //void write...
    void read(istream& is) {
        double x, y;
        cout<<"coord x: "; is>>x;
        cout<<"coord y: "; is>>y;
        this->Particle(x, y); //this is the questionable line
    }
};
```

If not, or if I'm completely wrong about the idea of serialization someone could show an alternative I'd be very thankful!

Comment: Why don't you just do `this->X = x; this->Y = y;`? Why are you trying to call a constructor?

Comment: meanwhile I just tried it, and I get error: invalid use of 'Particle::Particle'.
why does codeblocks offer the constructor as available member function?

Comment: @CodyGray because X and Y are private, thats the main issue

Comment: Good point. You should make them `protected` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that you mention won't compile. If you removed the "this->" it would compile, but then it just creates a new temporary Particle object that will be destroyed at the end of the function. So it will not set X, Y of your current object correctly and they won't change.

A possible solution would be to use "protected" for the variables X, Y (in case you don't want to define setters for each of them). This way the PParticle class (and all other derivate classes of Particle) would be able to access and modify them.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use:

```
this->Particle(x, y);
```

The language does not allow a constructor to be called on an object after it has been constructed.

**One solution**

Add member functions in `Particle` to set `x` and `y`.

```
class Particle {
    double X, Y;
public:
    Particle(double x=0, double y=0) :X(x), Y(y) {}

    void setX(double newX) { X = newX; }
    void setY(double newY) { Y = newY; }
};
```

Use them in `PParticle:read`.

```
void read(istream& is) {
    double x, y;
    is>>x;
    is>>y;
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
}
```

**PS**

I removed the lines

```
    cout<<"coord x: ";
    cout<<"coord y: ";
```

since they are useful only if you are reading from `cin`. If you read a `PParticle` from a file, they are useless.